# Run script on terminal at startup

Tags: script, bash, reboot

I want to run a command in a terminal (not background) every time my pi is completely booted (once it loads the desktop). I tried to edit the rc.local and add these commands `sleep 10` `chromium-browser` `cd path` `./script` but nothing happens. It doesn't even open the terminal so those commands are probably run in BG. Crontab makes the command run in BG too... is there a way to emulate me clicking on the terminal icon and typing in a few commands?

Here's my rc.local file

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "piexit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi
```

And then the commands added by me such as `sleep 10` and `chromium-browser`. There is also `exit 0` at the end

Comment: Do you really want the terminal to be interactive (i.e. as if you typed it into a new terminal), or are you just trying to debug why your script isn't working but would otherwise be happy for it to run in the background?

Comment: Also, I'd conjecture that the issue is `cd path`, `./script`. Replace those two lines with the **full path** of your script e.g. `/home/user/script` instead and test it again. Let me know if that works so I can post a full answer for you.

Comment: Ok, mine is a script that gives a live output about its status, and  it would be better if I could see it, so, yes I'd like my terminal to be interactive, but actually I'm trying to debug a script that isn't working (when it times out I reboot the system and that's why I need it to run at startup). I also need to open chromium at startup and, since crontab can't open GUI programs, I thought that opening a terminal and writing `chromium-browser` automatically at startup would be the best solution. What do you suggest?

Comment: But chromium-browser won't start anyway and it does not need the path, right? I think there's a problem with rc local how can I test it?

Comment: If `chromium-browser` doesn't run, either: `rc.local` isn't running at all (not likely); an error occurred before that line so the script stopped (possible) or the error occurred on that line.  Could you [edit] to include your full `rc.local`?

Comment: Ok I'll do it ASAP

Comment: Have you tried deleting the existing code and just using your script, then `exit 0`? Maybe that would work if there's an error that we've not noticed earlier in the script?

Comment: I tried and it still doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps try the full path of Chromium (`/usr/bin/chromium-browser`) instead? Maybe the PATH isn't as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting them into a script, for example ~/.start.sh
Add the commands. Then run chmod 755. 
sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
Then add @/home/pi/.start.sh.
This may work, I haven’t tested it.